# Show detail as navigationView in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, json, sencha-touch

I have a set of data that describes relations between people:

Example:

```
{
"entries":
[{"Name":"Jim",
"Friends":
[
{"friend" : "Peter" },
{"friend" : "Mike" },
{"friend" : "Fred",}
]

}, 
{"Name":"Peter",
 "Friends":
[
 {"friend" : "Jake"},
 {"friend" : "Sara"},
 {"friend" : "Mia"}
]
}
]
}
```

In the first view I create a List with alla the names within a navigationView. I my controller I then push a detailsview on itemtap showing the friends related to that particular name.

```
this.getName().push({
xtype: 'panel',
html: [

'<p>' + fetchRelations(data) + '</p>'
].join(''),
scrollable: true,
styleHtmlContent: true,
});
```

(fetchRelations basically just loopes through the friends array.)

This works fine. But with this approach I can't, in the next step, tap a name in the detailsview and see all his friends, and then the next person and so on, because the detailsview is a panel. When you tap a name, there may or may not be ny friends related to that name, and if there are no names, there should be no detailsview showing on itemtap, obviously.

I'm guessing that the detailsview must be a navigationView, but I don't know how to achieve this. A nod in the right direction very appreciated!

(Allreday posted this question in the sencha forum, but it has remianed unanswered for 12 hours, so that's why I try my luck here at SO)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a list to display the friends? Then listen to the itemtap or itemsingletap event where you can push the next view with the data related to the selected record...
You can use a navigationview to push the detailviews on or just a container with a card layout and handle the navigation yourself.